# How to disable all items in select box when i am selecting 'ALL' item using select2 jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am working in asp.net using select2 jquery. in my select box i have 10 items including 'ALL'.
my requirement is when i selected the ALL item , rest of the items must be disabled, when i remove the ALL tag, whole item should enabled.
http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/
    my jquery is written below.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#select1").select2({
        placeholder: 'Find and Select Books' 
     }).on("change", function (e) {
           alert(e.val)
    });
});
```

pls anyone help me????

html markup:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="header1" runat="server">
<title>JQuery Select2 Plug-in</title>
<script type="text/javascript"   src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="D:/DOTNET/ITS_GOOGLE_CHART_TABS_ListBOX/Scripts/select2- 3.4.1/select2.js"></script>
<link href="D:/DOTNET/ITS_GOOGLE_CHART_TABS_ListBOX/Scripts/select2-3.4.1/select2.css"  rel="stylesheet"/>

 </head>
 <body>
<form runat="server">
<select id="select1" runat="server" datasourceid="ds1" datatextfield="emp_name" multiple="true" style="width:300px"/>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="ds1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ connectionstrings:constr %>" SelectCommand="select top 10 * from emp" />

  </form>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#select1").select2({
        placeholder: 'Find and Select Books' 

     }).on("change", function (e) {

        alert(e.val)
    });

});


</script>
</html>

  C# code:
  select1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("ALL", "ALL"));
```

Comment: please share html code also

Comment: what are the values return by `select top 10 * from emp`? Could you please tell me from the source code of your html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than disabling the items on clicking `All` you can `select all the values` .The code is here :

```
$("#e1").select2();
$("#e1").on("change", function(e) {
    var selected = e.val;
    if ($.inArray("all", selected) !== -1) {
        var id = "e1"
        var element = $("#" + id);
        var selected = [];
        element.find("option").each(function(i, e) {
            if($(e).attr("value")=="all")
                selected[selected.length] = $(e).attr("value");
        });
        element.select2("val", selected);
    }
});
```

and the Jsfiddle link is http://jsfiddle.net/jEADR/734/ .
hope it helps ...

courtesy: @MarcusAsplund

Comment: thank u very much for replied. but i want when i select "ALL", rest them must disable

Comment: When you select All all the items are pushed in input box and no item will be shown in dropdown which is as good as disabling the options ..i mean why do you want to disable the items specifically ...

Comment: if select box has more than 100 items, it not good to show all.

Comment: will this work for you http://jsfiddle.net/jEADR/734/ . after selecting all you cannot select any option ...

Comment: your code is helped me. but i ca;t understand the coding . how would u restrict the other item when selecting "ALL"